# Дата и передача значения даты в mysql

Tags: дата, php, html5, javascript, mysql

Добрый день!!!
Мне нужно было сделать выборку в базе данных по максимальной дате, сам запрос построила и дату передавала вот таким способом

```
<p><label>Выберите дату <input type="date" name="seldate"/></label></p>
```

использовав html5, но к сажелению кроме браузера оперы, который открывает виджит этот элемент больше никто не поддерживат, каким способом можно это реализовать? или можно дописать javascript код чтобы это работало. Просто я не знаю javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая замечательная штучка как jQuery UI. Вот [тут](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) Вы можете любую красоту навести календарикам. А в html останется добавить только 1 класс для нужного поля.